# Revalidate after a certain time does not work in production environment under Vercel

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, page-refresh, swr

I have a problem with revalidate next.js. The following code works under Next.js 13.4.4 locally so with npm run dev. I host the whole thing on Vercel and the application runs on production environment so it doesn't get a new one after 5 seconds 'refresh' performed. Nothing happens. Does anyone have experience with it? Thank you

root/page.js

```
export default async function Home() {
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
const result = await 
fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/Products`, 
{
  next: { revalidate: 5 },
});
const pro = await result.json();
const products = pro.products;

if (session) 
{
 return (
      <div className="pb-10 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white ">
        //This Component is a 'use client' Component
        <MainImage products={products}></MainImage>
      </div>
        );
 }

 return <SignIn></SignIn>;

 }
}
```

Products/route.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { mongoConection } from "../../lib/mongoConnection";
import Product from "../model/Product/page";

export const revalidate = 5;

export async function GET() {
try {
 mongoConection();
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }

const allProducts = await Product.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
 return NextResponse.json({ products: allProducts }, { status: 200 });
}
```